# How can I force a Deferred method to execute immediately?

Tags: javascript, performance, asynchronous, dojo, deferred

I have a web-mapping application which has a button that when clicked calls a web service that returns a large JSON. Part of the JSON string represents a spatial extent that I need to zoom the map to. The main guts of the JSON (the "results" section below) takes several seconds to process and is unrelated to the "extentToZoomTo" section.  The mapping API I am using has a setExtent method that returns a **DOJO Deferred** object. The setExtent method produces an image *on the server* and can take a few seconds to complete. What I would like to do is to call the setExtent method immediately after I get the JSON, and  while the server is busy working on that, the client javaScript code on the browser can work on the "results" section of the JSON simultaneously.  How can I make that happen??  What I have found is that if I simply call setExtent before I start processing the "results" section, it doesn't actually send that request to the server until *after* the results section has been completely processed.  I can verify that behavior by inspecting the Network tab in the developer tools (there is a several second gap between when I get the JSON and when the setExtent method is called). I'm guessing that this has something to do with the fact that setExtent is deferred.  How can I get it to fire right away?

```
{
  "extentToZoomTo": {
    "xmin": 1234,
    "ymin": 4567,
    "xmax": 2345,
    "ymax": 5678
  },
  "results": {
          //A very large amount of data here that takes several seconds to process
  }
}
```

---- EDIT ---
Can I run two Deferred's in parallel somehow? Pseudo TypeScript code below

```
mainMethod(){
    let bigJSONString: string = "big json string with results and extent info retrieved from web service call";
    //get extent info from bigJSONString...for now, just mock the values
    let xmin = 123; let ymin = 234; let xmax = 345; let ymax = 789;
    let jsonExtent: esri.geometry.Extent = new esri.geometry.Extent(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax, spatialRef);
    //I want to call setExtent and handResults in parallel...how do I do that?
    let setExtentDeferred: dojo.Deferred = myMap.setExtent(jsonExtent);
    let handleResultsDeferred: dojo.Deferred = this.handleResultsDeferred(bigJSONString);
    dojo.Deferred.RUN_IN_PARALLEL(setExtentDeferred, handleResultsDeferred);
}

handleResultsDeferred(jsonString: string): dojo.Deferred {
//This code does the real work...should I return a dojo.Deferred from here?
    return new dojo.Deferred();
}
```

Comment: You can use 2 Deferreds and run them in parallel. You can use dojo/deferred/all to do something after the 2 responses come back. Post in some code if you need more help.

Comment: Philipe - thank you for getting back to me. I'm not quite sure how to do what you are suggesting.

Comment: You would need to split the backend into 2 separate endpoints. One that returns extentToZoomTo, and another that returns the results. Do you have control on the backend?

Comment: I don't have control over myMap.setExtent. I do have control over handleResultsDeferred. myMap.setExtent will result in a network call, while handleResults is all client JavaScript.

Comment: Looks like you are using pre-AMD dojo. Check https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/deferreds/

Answer (score 0):

A Deferred object is similar to a standard JavaScript Promise or a Java Future. It's just a way for code to be notified when a background process completes. This is different from how the word "defer" is used in some other languages such as Go, where it's indicating that an operation is being deferred until later.

However...the `setExtent` method may still be deferred until after the handleResults code. If the code in `setExtent` that makes the JSON request is running in a `setTimeout` or in some other async fashion, it will be deferred until the next tick of the JavaScript event loop, which will be after the other result handling code (assuming it's synchronous).

The `setExtent` code actually has two levels of async. First, the function code is async (that's why you don't see the request being issued until after you expect it). The second is the request itself. It would look something like:

```
    let jsonExtent = expo.Extent
+---let setExtentDeferred = myMap.setExtent(jsonExtent);
|   handleResults()
|   // any other sync code runs
|
|   -- current event loop cycle ends --
|
+-> // setExtent code actually runs here and starts a request
    // other sync code runs

    -- time passes --

    // request completes
```

The sync operations run in sequence, and any async operations are deferred until a bit later.

To get some things running in parallel, you'll need to get the handling code started after the request is issued, but before it's complete. Note that the request is the only part of this that can really run in parallel with anything else. Barring newer features like service workers, JavaScript code is single threaded, and only a few operations like requests can actually be doing things at the same time as JavaScript code is running.

To get the handling code to start after the JSON request is initiated, you'll just need to defer it until the next tick of the JS event loop. If you actually want to be notified when the `setExtent` request *and* the processing have completed, you can use a DeferredList. Note that the DeferredList doesn't run the deferreds in any special fashion (a Deferred is just a notifier, not a thing to be run), it's just a way of letting you know when they have both completed.

```
mainMethod(){
    let bigJSONString: string = "big json string";
    let xmin = 123; let ymin = 234; let xmax = 345; let ymax = 789;
    let jsonExtent = new esri.geometry.Extent(...);
    let setExtentDeferred = myMap.setExtent(jsonExtent);
    let handleResultsDeferred = this.handleResultsDeferred(bigJSONString);
    let dfd = dojo.DeferredList([setExtentDeferred, handleResultsDeferred]);
    // dfd will resolve when both setExtentDeferred and handleResultsDeferred
    // have resolved.
}

handleResultsDeferred(jsonString: string): dojo.Deferred {
    let dfd = new dojo.Deferred();
    // Run code in a setTimeout with no timeout -- the goal isn't to delay it
    // for any period of time, but just to defer it until the next tick of the
    // JS event loop.
    setTimeout(function () {
        // do work here
        dfd.resolve();
    });
    return dfd;
}
```

This will give you something like:

```
      let jsonExtent = expo.Extent
+-----let setExtentDeferred = myMap.setExtent(jsonExtent);
| +---let handleResultsDeferred = handleResults()
| |   // any other sync code runs
| |
| |   -- current event loop cycle ends --
| | 
+-|-> // setExtent code actually runs, starting a request
  +-> // handle results code runs

      -- time passes --

      // request completes
      // DeferredList resolves
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply - I tried what you suggested, but the network call generated from setExtent still doesn't kick off until after the Results have been processed.  Maybe I'm doing something wrong. In setExtentDeferred, I'm assuming I should also pass back a dojo.deferred, correct? Should I call .resolve() in both setExtentDeferred and handleResultsDeferred?  Since map.setExtent itself returns a deferred, maybe I don't even need a setExtentDeferred method.

Comment: Where are you calling a `setExtentDeferred` method? As you say, if `setExtent` returns a deferred, you don't need to do anything else when calling it.

Comment: I'm no longer calling setExtentDeferred, just map.setExtent.  I needed to pass an outer context into setTimeout() and it has null for the second timeout argument. That's ok, right? Basically, this is it:
```
let dfd = new dojo.DeferredList([map.setExtent(extent), this.setResultsDeferred()]).then(() => {
  //done
});

setResultsDeferred(): dojo.Deferred  {
    let dfd = new dojo.Deferred();
    let context = this;
    setTimeout(function () {//A bunch of work...
     let x = context.getSomething();
     dfd.resolve();
  }, null, collection, context);
  return dfd;
}
```

Comment: Yes, you don't actually need a timeout, so leaving it out or setting it to 0 is fine. Just out of curiosity, is there some reason you're passing the context parameter in as a parameter to setTimeout?

Comment: Within the setTimeout, the work that setResults needs to do requires access to some data that was previously performed.  In TypeScript at least, I can't access that data using this.myData, because "this" refers to something else.  So by passing it in, I can get around that.

Comment: Assigning `this` to a local variable `context` outside of the setTimeout callback is all you need to do; the code in the callback will be able to use `context` directly due to the magic of closures.